# Reduce function on Map Reduce showing incorrect results -- why?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I have a data structure that keeps track of people in different cities:

```
//in db.persons
{
  name: "John",
  city: "Seattle
},
{
  name: "Bill",
  city: "Portland"
}
```

I want to run a map reduce to get a list of how many people are in each city, so the result will look like this:

```
{
  _id: "Seattle",
  value: 10
}
```

My map reduce function looks like this:

```
map = function(){
  var city = this.city
  emit(city, 1);
};


reduce = function(key, values){
    var result = 0;
    values.forEach(function(value){
      result += 1;
    });
    return result;
}
```

Very simple stuff, I figured it would take the `city` as a key, then add one to the result for each matching city it found. However, on the resulting map reduce, the value was off by a large factor. Switching my reduce function to:

```
reduce = function(key, values){
    var result = 0;
    values.forEach(function(value){
      result += value;
    });
    return result;
}
```

And adding the `value` to the result (which should be 1, as I understand it from my `emit` function) returned correct results.

Why are the results different? Wouldn't my `value` be 1 in the reduce function?

Comment: It seems like your `reduce` function isn't going to work: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/#requirements-for-the-reduce-function

Comment: Which one? The first one or the second one?

Comment: The docs say both. `reduce` should return a result that can be passed back into `reduce`. Something like `{city: "Seattle", population: 123}`. If the `population` key isn't present, assume it's `1`.

Comment: Hmm... well it certainly works. And returning an object from my reduce function seems to blow things up. I'm going to take another peek at those docs [*edit*] it blows up because I return an object from the reduce function with an arbitrary key, then reduce runs *n* times on that key trying to reduce it

Comment: This is to do with batching of the results, how many people in the cirties you tested? when you do `emit(city,1)` you merge the `1` into the key `city`

Answer (score 1):

This happens because MongoDB can invoke the reduce function multiple times for the same key. Here's a simple worked example:

Lets say you have just three documents in your database, each with same 'city' of 'Seattle'. After the emit phase, you will have a set of emitted objects which look like

`{'Seattle' : 1}. {'Seattle' : 1}. {'Seattle' : 1}`

After the emit phase has completed, the reduce phase starts. In the simplest case, the reduce function will be called as `reduce('Seattle', [1,1,1])`. In this case, your first function would work correctly. However, the reduce function may be called multiple times:

`reduce('Seattle', [1,1]) -> {'Seattle' : 2}, {'Seattle', 1}`

`reduce('Seattle', [2,1])`

In this case, your first reduce function would return `2` after the second reduce call as there are two items in the list of values. In your second reduce function, you correctly add the values together rather than just counting them, which gives the correct answer.

I personally think that the [CouchDB docs](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Introduction_to_CouchDB_views#Restrictions_on_map_and_reduce_functions) explain this slightly better as to why you need to have commutative and associative reduce functions for their array of values input.